# toolkit:ExpanderView in Listbox

Tags: xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8, silverlight-toolkit

I have troubles with binding data to a Listbox to dynamically create ExpanderView.

I have used Listboxes in my Code before, so I'm not sure if the binding is really the problem. Am I setting the contents of ExpanderView wrong?

My Code so far in XAML:

```
                <ListBox x:Name="Newsticker_Listbox">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <toolkit:ExpanderView Header="{Binding}" Expander="{Binding}" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                              HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource CustomHeaderTemplate}"
                             ExpanderTemplate="{StaticResource CustomExpanderTemplate}"
                              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CustomItemTemplate}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

the Templates:

```
<!--newsfeed templates-->
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CustomHeaderTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CustomExpanderTemplate">
        <Image Source="{Binding Subtitle}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CustomItemTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

I'm binding with

```
ObservableCollection<news> newslist = new ObservableCollection<news>();
//populate
Newsticker_Listbox.ItemsSource = newslist;
```

news is a really simple object, it just stores some strings, which can be read out by news.Title, news.Subtitle etc

I've used the example from http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/expand-and-collapse-expanderview-inside-data-bound-listbox-via-code as basic for my code, I've just simplified it for my cause (mabye too much?)

Help is very appreciated, thank you all in advance

**EDIT**

This code works so far, but why does the solution with templates not work?

```
<ListBox x:Name="Newsticker_Listbox">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <toolkit:ExpanderView>
                                    <toolkit:ExpanderView.Header>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Titel}" />
                                    </toolkit:ExpanderView.Header>
                                    <toolkit:ExpanderView.Expander>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Untertitel}" />
                                    </toolkit:ExpanderView.Expander>
                                    <toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
                                    </toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>
                                </toolkit:ExpanderView>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

Comment: of what type is newlist? if it is `List<SomeClass>` or `ObservableCollection<SomeClass>` or any other collection of `SomeClass`, please post your `SomeClass`  definition in question

Comment: Yeah you're right I forgot the definition. I've edited the Post.

Comment: Try to remove this part: `ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}"` from ListBox definition in XAML. Since you assigned ListBox's ItemsSource from code, I think you don't need to bind ItemsSource in XAML

Comment: The Expanders still won't show up, but I've tried this with other listboxes, and indeed there was no difference with or without ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}". 
Mabye this was part of the solution, thanks!

Comment: I've found out that `ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}"` is added when using Blend with sample Data.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `Header={Binding}` and `Expander={Binding}` XAML code. It is overriding your custom HeaderTemplate and ExpanderTemplate.

You bound the Header and the Expander to the context of the application, which it doesn't really understand, so the binding resolved itself to nothing, so your ExpanderView displays nothing.

Comment: This did unfortunately not solve my problem. Also when I removed `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` too, there were still no Items displayed.